# Why swift compiler doesn't find Alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I try to install Alamofire. I really haven't possibility to use cocoaPods, so I try to install it manually.

The steps I took:

1. I download Alamofire from GitHub.
2. In folder drag Alamofire.xcodeproj and drop into my projects
3. In my projects in "generals" in "Embedded Binaries" add framework for iOs
4. import Alamofire in code

When I want to make a request I enter "Alamofire" and swift offers me "AlamofireExtended", "AlamofireNotifications", "AlamofireExtension" and "AlamofireVersionNumber".
I try to enter request manually, but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow their [guidelines](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for manual installation?

You should run

```
$ git init
```

(if your project is not initialized as a git repository)
and then

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
```

(so that you can add it as a submodule)

I would also suggest you to delete the derived data, clean the project and then build it again.

Comment: Yes, I follow this guidelines

Comment: Try also to select the schema -> Alamofire, then run. If it compiles, then change schema back to the project and it will work without issues.